# Customization of Grid View

Tags: grid, customization, android-view

I want to create a shelf view. I explore various codes also, but those are quite complex. I have an idea to implement the same but i am not sure for that. 
Can we place a background drawable to the grid row wise??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring, i got the solution. The solution require two steps:

1.Creation of class which extends GridView Class.

2.Adding this class in to the layout in which grid view needs to be display.

For better understanding "http://erikwallentinsen.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/android-row-background-in-gridview/" will help you.

Comment: As per the link specified above,i have set the background drawable at the constructor. The drawable is a shelf image with special effect on both sides of shelf pane. Now the problem i am facing is the drawable is repeating rather than stretching itself. Due to this the shelf pane is getting distorted from middle.Please advice.